# Is it possible in Node js to handle routs outside of app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodes

I'm trying to better organize my node project. I'm doing so by moving all the code that has deals with handling routs to a file outside of app.js.

**This is a screenshot of the code I wish to move to another javaScript file**

[image]

I tried putting this code in another file and requiring that file and then got my project to run but when I visit any route int the URL it will say something like "can't get /login" in the browser.

From the little experience I have, it seems that express dose not listen when I try to use the code

```
app.use(example);
```

anywhere other than in app.js.

Question:
How Can get the code in the screenshot to work in a file other than app.js in order to reduce the lines of code in app.js

Comment: [Images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are unhelpful, and even the code in that image isn't sufficient for anyone to reproduce the problem. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://expressjs.com/de/guide/routing.html#express-router

Answer (score 1):

Make use of middleware to accomplish this.
If you want to make a folder or file where all the controllers are present, require express-router in your router.js file(s). To require express-router in router.js add:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
```

Add this file in your app.js or index.js using:

```
var exampleController = require("./routers/router.js")
```

Also give the path where 'exampleController' is to be used. Considering you want it to be used for Login/Authentication. After requiring it in app.js, add:

```
app.use('/authenticate', exampleController)
```

After this whenever the client tries to access the '/authenticate' path or anything nested inside it, your server will use the router.js file to perform all the operations, like get and post. Be sure to not use the complete path when you are in your router.js file. For example if the path is '/authenticate/register'. Your code  for basic and get and post requests should be:

```
router.route("/register")
.get(function(req,res){
   //Handle get requests
})
.post(function(req,res){
   //Handle post requests
 })
```

Now instead of 'app' you can use 'router' in the router.js file and it will work the same. It is like a 'mini-app'.For using this, Do give this last part express documentation on routing a read : https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.